# How do I change contour color plot to make it more readable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale, contour

I want to make a contour plot, with a specific contour line using matplotlib, the important piece of code is the following:

```
levels = [-5, -3,-2,-1, 0,1, 2,5,10,17.5]
cax = ax1.contourf(X,Y,Z,levels)
#some similar code
```

In the end, is scale of the contour plot is the on the following picture, however, I don't like that the contour between (-5,0) becomes only variants of dark blue and purple, How can I make the colour scale more varied, without needing to change the scale?

[image]

Comment: Check the `colors` parameter. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html

Comment: pass the `cmap` argument. Colormaps are described here https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html

Comment: The question lacks a complete [mre]. Please review [Creating Effective Stack Overflow Questions](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/Creating_Effective_StackOverflow_Questions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

There are several things that could help you

1. use a different colormap (e.g., `cm.PRGrn`)
2. use `ax.contour(...)` to draw contour lines across the boundaries of different levels
3. do not use `ax.contourf(...)` at all, but a combination of `ax.imshow(...)` and `ax.contour(...)`, as it's shown in the right subplot; note the differences in the two colorbars.

This is the code used to produce the figure at the top.
[Matplotlib's example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_image.html) recommends using the exact `levels` that are recomputed in the filled contour object; note also `extend='both'` in `ax.contourf`'s parameters.

The code for `ax.imshow` is relatively straightforward, note the use of `extent` to have correct axis limits, `origin='lower'` to have the *y* axis going upwards, and the (optional) use of `TwoSlopeNorm` to have the colormap centered about zero and extending to the data extremes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import PRGn
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm

x = y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 81)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = 5*X + 4*Y + 4 - 2

levels = [-5, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 17.5]
extent = (-2, 2, -2, 2)

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 4), layout='constrained')

cf0 = ax0.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=levels, cmap=PRGn, extend='both')
cc0 = ax0.contour( X, Y, Z, levels=cf0.levels, colors='k')
cl0 = ax0.clabel(cc0)
cb0 = fig.colorbar(cf0, ax=ax0)
ax0.set_aspect(1)

im1 = ax1.imshow(Z, extent=extent, origin='lower', cmap=PRGn, norm=TwoSlopeNorm(0))
cc1 = ax1.contour(Z, levels, colors='k', origin='lower', extent=extent)
cl1 = ax1.clabel(cc1)
cb1 = fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```